# Enigmail plugin does not recognize anymore my private key

Tags: debian, gpg, thunderbird, enigmail

I am using a Debian unstable with Iceweasel (38.2.0esr-1) and the Enigmail plugin (2:1.8.2-3) from the distribution packages. I recently upgraded my system and got a new version of the gnupg2 package (2.1.7-2, previous was 2.0.28-2) and I ran into problems when trying to use my private key (encrypt, decrypt, sign messages) in Enigmail since then. The error message is:

> Enigmail: Error - no matching private/secret key found to decrypt message;
>   click on 'Details' button for more information

And, the 'Details' button was giving the following error message:

```
Enigmail Security Info
Error - no matching private/secret key found to decrypt message
gpg: decryption failed: No secret key
Note: The message is encrypted for the following User ID's / Keys:
  0xAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA (Surname Name <surname.name@mailbox.net),
  0xAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
```

Note also, that, if I save the e-mail in a flat file and use the `gpg2 --decrypt` command line, it works like a charm without any visible problem.

I looked in the Debian BTS about Enigmail and found a bug with similar characteristics ([Debian Bug #794627](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=794627)). It has not been solved because the maintainer cannot reproduce the bug.

I tried several things with no success, so if you encounter this bug and find something about it, I would be pleased to know how to solve it. Any input is welcome.

Comment: try `apt-get install -f`

Comment: @gwillie: In fact, what you propose is simply irrelevant because it is a bug inside a packet (and not 'about the dependancies of my system').

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In fact, the problem is linked to the usage of the `gnome3-pinentry` software when agent has no default `DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS`.

Here is the [thread on the Debian BTS (Bug Tracking System) Website](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=794627) about this problem.

It finally turned out that the default `pinentry` software is working as expected, but the Gnome3 version has some quirks about dispatching some variables. Here is the patch applied by the Debian Enigmail maintainer to fix the problem:

```
enigmail (2:1.8.2-4) unstable; urgency=medium

  * pass through {GTK,QT}_IM_MODULE, XMODIFIERS, and
    DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS so that modern pinentry works. (Closes: #794627)
  * correct reported version number of enigmail

 -- Daniel Kahn Gillmor <dkg@fifthhorseman.net>  Thu, 20 Aug 2015 00:23:48 +0200
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you can correctly decrypt using GPG via command line, it looks like it's an issue with the Enigmail configuration.  Open Iceweasel, go to *Account Settings -> OpenPGP Security* and verify that:

- *Enable OpenPGP support for this identity* is checked
- *Use specific OpenPGP KeyID* is checked and set to the ID of your key pair